# Coupon codes and wordress; Membership plugin, tertiary plugin or shopping cart?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, membership

## TL;DR

Is there a membership plugin for Wordpress that supports coupon codes to discount the total price of a membership *before* the customer is whisked away to the hosted checkout page (1ShoppingCart, MoneyBookers, etc.)?

## Backstory:

I'm facing a dilemma with a paid membership site and the use of coupon codes. My site's basic structure / business model is this:

- There will be premium content that is blocked by a pay wall.
- To access the premium content, customers must pay a one-time, non-recurring fee for lifetime access.
- I would like the ability for customers to use a coupon code at or near the checkout page to reduce the price.

The coupon code weighs heavily in my conversion tactic / marketing plan. (For those interested in the specifics, I hope to use the tool [JustUno](http://www.justuno.com/) to offer money off of the purchase price in exchange for a tweet or Facebook like.)

My trouble comes concerning at which point to implement the coupon feature:

1. At the membership plugin level (Wishlist, MagicMembers, S2Members Pro, etc.)
2. At the hosted checkout page level (1ShoppingCart, MoneyBookers, etc.)
3. Using some extra plugin within WordPress. Somehow. Someway.

## Specific Dilemma:

The major membership plugins that I've seen don't support coupons internally. There's only a handful of major checkout pages I've seen that support coupons (Authorize.net and MoneyBookers being the biggest two of note). Of those checkout pages / payment gateways / merchant accounts none support payment through PayPal which is rather important to me. PayPal themselves don't support coupons at their checkout page, thus I need to use someone else for the checkout and then merely offer PayPal as a possible payment method.

Finally there is the problem of using a plugin-for-a-plugin, i.e. a plugin for the membership management system that allows for coupons to be implemented pre-checkout. It might not be supported or might not be reliable.

## Question(s):

Finally, a question or three!

- Most importantly, is there a membership plugin that supports coupon codes internally?
- Would I be better off using coupon codes on the checkout page?
- Should I even consider plugins-to-a-plugin / custom coding to implement coupons into a membership program that doesn't internally do coupons?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at Restrict Content? Discount codes are applied before the user is directed to paypal.

Pro Version: http://pippinsplugins.com/restrict-content-pro-premium-content-plugin
Free version: http://pippinsplugins.com/restricted-content-plugin-free/

Comment: Thanks David! I'm looking at it now. I bumped into WP-Members and a few other membership plugins, and am trying to winnow them down to the best ones possible.